# SQL Server "Cannot find the symmetric key 'DataFilePasswordKey'" though I created it and I'm a db_owner

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2019 Enterprise, I have Dev, Test, and Production instances of a database on separate servers. I am in the db_owner role on all three. I've created master key, certificate, and symmetric key on each for the purpose of encrypting one column in one table.

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION
BY PASSWORD = '[password]'
GO

CREATE CERTIFICATE DataFileCert
   WITH SUBJECT = 'Data File Info';
GO

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY DataFileKey
    WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
    ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE DataFileCert;
GO
```

Following this, on the Dev and Test servers, I can run this with no problem:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY DataFileKey
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE DataFileCert;
```

On Production, I get the error "Cannot find the symmetric key 'DataFileKey', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.".

I can see both the certificate and the symmetric key in the Object Explorer. I can also DROP both the key and the certificate and am then able to start over. So I know it exists, and I even have permission to drop it.

Given these circumstances--that I'm the one who created the master key, the certificate, and the symmetric key, and that I'm in the db_owner role on all three instances--what could be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your user has both of:

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON CERTIFICATE :: DataFileCert TO [userName]
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SYMMETRIC KEY :: DataFileKey TO [userName]
```

On the certificate you used to create the key, and the key itself.

Comment: As I said, I created them, I'm in db_owner for the database, and I'm the user who can't open the key--but only on one out of the three servers. *Even so* I tried to grant myself VIEW DEFINITION and couldn't.

Comment: You may need a user with sysadmin or security admin to grant these permissions for you. If you have either of those roles on the other servers it may explain what you're experiencing